# Low quality posts

Tags: support, quality-filter

Some time back,I was trying to ask a question.(Find the smallest positive integer $a$ such that 1971 divides $50^n+a.23^n$ for odd n.)
This is what I got: "Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

```
* It does not meet our quality standards."
```

Can anyone kindly explain what this is all about?I am new to this website.Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what the problem was, but I would have suggested you rewrite the question to look less like an order.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's not much to explain. To prevent too many low-quality questions, there's a script that looks for certain properties that low-quality questions share (I don't know the details; I assume it has something to do with length, perhaps capitalization, etc.) and prevents users from posting questions with too many of those properties, or something like that. Try rephrasing it and/or adding more detail. The source of the question wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I managed to post the problem.And I certainly apologize if my tone somehow sounded more like a command than a request.